# Window.Open() opens a new Tab but with no File URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to open new tab using Window Open under javascript as below:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",url:"GetData.php?m="+e.series.key,
       dataType: "json"}).done
       (function( FolderPath )//i get the folder path under this variable
    {
        OpenInNewTab(url);//url="file://///NetworkSharePath/Folder1/Folder2" -->URL Value
    });

function OpenInNewTab(url) {
 var win = window.open(url , '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

Observation:
It opens a new Tab but not the desired Path.
Note:

- I have added Local Links for Chrome as an extension.
- When i paste the same url in browser, its able to load the directory structure
- When i try to open http://www.google.com, it redirects the new tab correctly.
  Not sure what am I missing, please share inputs

Comment: looks like cross origin because CRX has origin `chrome-extension://`, which is definitely different from `file://`

Comment: okay, please elaborate, i am afraid i did not understand what are you trying to imply.

Comment: Opening files on a local filesystem/ network share (i.e. an untrusted source as it doesn't have a PKI Certificate Chain, because it's a filesystem) is not a thing that Chrome likes, so you end up with cross origin issues as Chrome can't validate that your page's requests are all from the same origin.

Comment: okay, is it different when we try to paste url in the Address bar?

Comment: If you access a file directly via an URL, it's different as you're directly accessing it so there are no cross origin issues.